# Question about Matrix Algebra and Log(M)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi Guys I am trying to understand this example that came from wikipedia

If a matrix A

\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\theta)      & -sin(\theta) \\
    \sin(\theta)       & cos(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}

Then $Log (A) =(\theta +2\pi n) B$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Where $B$ is the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
  0      & -1 \\
 1      & 0
\end{bmatrix}

I am trying to prove this to improve my understanding and so far I am thinking along the lines:
In order to verify the statement we can take 
$$Log (A) =e^{(\theta +2\pi n) B}$$
Then we can exponentiate, thus obtaining 
$$A =e^{(\theta +2\pi n) B}$$

$$A =e^{(\theta +2\pi n)}e^{ B}$$

Where to obtain $e^B$ we have to use its Jordan form/ diagonal matrix i.e. $B=T^{-1}JT$ to do this we find the eighen values which are $-i$ and $i$. Then I am not sure what exactly to do to finish this I want to use that the $e^{diagA}$=diag of the $e^{\lambda}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that's wrong.
$A$ can be diagonalized: $A = S^{-1} D S$ where
$$ D = \pmatrix{e^{i\theta} & 0\cr 0 & e^{-i\theta}\cr},\ S = \pmatrix{i/2 & -i/2\cr 1/2 & 1/2\cr}$$
Thus the logarithms of $A$ are of the form
$$ S^{-1} \text{Log}(D) S = S^{-1} \pmatrix{i\theta + 2\pi i m & 0 \cr 0 & -i\theta + 2 \pi i n\cr} S = \pmatrix{i\pi(m+n) & (n-m)\pi - \theta\cr (m-n)\pi + \theta & i \pi (m+n)\cr} $$
where $m$ and $n$ are arbitrary integers.

In particular there is no need to have $m+n=0$.

Comment: Sorry I see your logic, I was going by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix       Am I misunderstanding the statement?

Comment: What it says there is $(\theta + 2 \pi n) \pmatrix{0 & -1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$ is **a** logarithm of $A$ for each $n$.  It does not say that those are **all** the logarithms of $A$.

Comment: I am very sorry I made a typo. I have corrected it now it is $(\theta +2\pi n)B$ not $(\theta +2\pi) nB$